# Genealogytree: Minimal sandclock example

Tags: genealogytree

I am having trouble with package genealogytree, and the documentation file [found on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/genealogytree) seems complex.

Could someone give me a minimal example of a sand clock graph (two siblings sharing two parents and each having a child) please?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far, and exactly what you are having difficulty with?

Comment: Welcome. // You can find more e.g. by clicking on the tag "genealogytree" below your question, or by following Related links to the right.

Comment: The manual is indeed rather complex (382 pages!). However, there is a tutorial in the manual (starting from page 15) which shows the basics step by step in a very readable way. Once you get to page 19 you can probably create the sandclock graph that you asked about.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}

\section{A rendition of the desired result}
minimal example of a sand clock graph \\two siblings \textbf{sonA, daughterB} \\sharing two parents \textbf{father, mother} \\and each having a child \textbf{sonA1, daughterA2, daughterB1, daughterB2}
\section{Things to keep in mind}
sandclock must have a \textbf{child} node\\there can be a \textbf{mix} of child and parent nodes\\every node with prefix \textbf{g, p} will render in the same row\\ every node with prefix \textbf{g,c} will render in the same row\\you have to finish the tree in \textbf{one sitting} else lose track of the flow\\

    \begin{genealogypicture}
            [template=formal graph]
            sandclock{ 
            child{
                g[male]{father}                 p[female]{mother}           
                child{
                    g[male]{sonA}
                    c[male]{sonA1}              c[female]{daughterA2}
                        }
                child{
                    g[female]{daughterB}
                    c[female]{daughterB1}   c[female]{daghterB2}
                        }
                    }
            parent{
            g[male]{grandfather}    
                        }
            parent{
            g[female]{grandmother}
                        }
        }
    \end{genealogypicture}




\end{document}
```

[image]